# GetShortPathName() return garbled when feeding particular path

Tags: c#, kernel32

Our team have used the following code for years

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern Int32 GetShortPathName(string path, StringBuilder shortPath, int shortPathLength);

public static string GetShortPathName(string longPath)
{
    StringBuilder shortPath = new StringBuilder(longPath.Length + 1);

    if (0 == GetShortPathName(longPath, shortPath, shortPath.Capacity))
    {
        return longPath;
    }

    return shortPath.ToString();
}
```

Somewhen last week we had a report that our application stops working. After troubleshooting we found when feeding the following path to the `GetShortPathName()` and it returns path with garbled inside.

```
\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\58.6.5\winpex32.wim
```

So I was trying to find the pattern but couldn't find any...

```
var r1 = GetShortPathName(@"\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\58.6.5\winpex32.wim"); // r1 = \\?\C:\Disks\WDT\586~1.5䳸ĴDšóó%
var r2 = GetShortPathName(@"\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\test\winpex32.wim");   // r2 = \\?\C:\Disks\WDT\test\winpex32.wim
var r3 = GetShortPathName(@"\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\1.2.3\winpex32.wim");  // r3 = \\?\C:\Disks\WDT\1.2.3\winpex32.wim
var r4 = GetShortPathName(@"\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\11.6.5\winpex32.wim"); // r4 = \\?\C:\Disks\WDT\11.6.5\winpex32.wim
var r5 = GetShortPathName(@"\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\58.6.6\winpex32.wim"); // r5 = \\?\C:\Disks\WDT\58.6.6\winpex32.wim
var r6 = GetShortPathName(@"\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\58.6.4\winpex32.wim"); // r6 = \\?\C:\Disks\WDT\58.6.4\winpex32.wim
var r7 = GetShortPathName(@"\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\0.6.5\winpex32.wim");  // r7 = \\?\C:\Disks\WDT\0.6.5\winpex32.wim
var r8 = GetShortPathName(@"\\?\C:\X\WDT\58.6.5\winpex32.wim");     // r8 = \\?\C:\X\WDT\58.6.5\winpex32.wim
var r9 = GetShortPathName(@"\\?\C:\Disks\T\58.6.5\winpex32.wim");   // r9 = \\?\C:\Disks\T\58.6.5\winpex32.wim
var r10 = GetShortPathName(@"\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\58.6.5\wx.wim");      // r10 = \\?\C:\Disks\WDT\58.6.5\wx.wim
```

All the others work fine except r1 and I'm running out of ideas.

What causes the garbled in this particular case and what can I do to prevent it?

[image]

Comment: FYI: I just tried your code and don't get an error.  My guess is it's somehow related to regional settings given your username and some of the characters in the faulty path...

Comment: Are there many files in the 58.6.5 directory? Did you run a `chkdsk` on the drive? What does _"stop working"_ mean, exactly, what solution are you looking for?

Comment: @CodeCaster: The issue is related to the output of `r1` which resolves `\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\58.6.5\winpex32.wim` to `\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\586~1.5䳸ĴDšóó%`.

Comment: @John yes, I understand that, but I'm trying to help the OP probe for the cause of that output. The MFT might be corrupt, I guess. As for the question about "not working", this is not their code that is "not working", they should provide a more appropriate problem description.

Comment: @CodeCaster: You'd said "what does stop working mean"; I was pointing out that it meant that the above path is not resolved correctly.  I guess your question was "did the path exist prior to the issue"; i.e. did the issue occur because of a new filename not previously used, because of a corrupt disk, or because of some upgrade/patch, etc.

Comment: @蕭為元 FYI: My system's Win 7 Pro SP1 (7.1.7601) with en-gb regional settings.  I tested your code in LinqPad 5.

Comment: @CodeCaster there is only one file. Our program does not work as expected since the return path has garbled. I'm not sure what I should look for, I don't understand why it didn't work in this particular case, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: I gave you one hint where to start, being to check the disk for errors. What does `dir /x` show for that file? And the problem is that attempting to use the path returned by `GetShortPathName()` in another function (which one?) causes errors?

Comment: @JohnLBevan thanks, I will survey a bit to see if it has something to do with regional settings.

Comment: There is more wrong, the returned strings are not actually short names.  Probably because they are not real directories, but "58.6.5" is.  So your tests don't prove anything.  The short name for "58.6.5" is not properly zero-terminated, a pretty classic C language bug.  Or its directory entry is corrupted, start there first.  Next start killing off the kind of processes that like to interfere with a program using the file system, cloud storage utilities and anti-malware.  And consider that it might have been caused by heap corruption in the program that created the directory.

Comment: @HansPassant well, I wonder about that too but it's a tiny module of a huge system and I didn't have much context for the whole usage that why the input doesn't seem to fit something able to convert to a short path? appreciate your help and reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found that every time the garbled is slightly different.
Which makes me wonder if somehow `GetShortPathName()` can't properly store the result to `StringBuilder`, and Yes it was, I didn't provide enough space to `StringBuilder` which result in all these messes.

Once I add sufficient volume of capacity

```
StringBuilder shortPath = new StringBuilder(260);
```

I can retrieve the path without garbled.

```
\\?\C:\Disks\WDT\586~1.5\winpex32.wim
```

Comment: Ah, yes, the short path for "58.6.5" is 1 character longer.  +2 is not good enough, try 58.6.5\58.6.5 for example.  Consider to use new StringBuilder(260) instead.  These kind of buffer overflows are pretty exploitable, you can send an email message to secure@microsoft.com to let them know.

Comment: [Reference for capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)